# WooCommerce: Check if subcategory has specific parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display content based on the current category and its parent category.
To do that, I need to know if the current category is a subcategory of a specific parent category.

For example, these are my categories:

1. Cars

   - Sportcars

     - Italian sportcars
2. Bikes

   - Dirtbikes

     - Japanese dirtbikes

I now want to display the content in on every category archive down the category tree.
In Cars, Sportcars and Italian sportcars for example.

For the first category I can use a Conditional Tag from WooCommerce:

```
is_product_category( 'cars' )
```

But there is no `in_product_category()`. So I could not check, if the categegory "Italian sportcars" is a child of "Cars".

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the Parent Category of your category using the below code.

```
$parentcats = get_ancestors($product_cat_id, 'product_cat');
```

You will get one or more parent categories, as an array and loop over it to get the value like below:

```
foreach($parentcat in $parentcats){
    echo $parentcat;
}
```

Then you can compare it with your "Specific Category" using an IF CONDITION and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for parent category property on the child category object. A child category has a parent property that holds the ID of its parent category.
In your case the 'Italian sportcars' term object would have a parent property the points to the ID of 'Car' term.